Formula to find proper column based on criteria
I have a dataset with several hierarchy columns where I need to find the second-level manager if they are < band 6. Here is what my data looks like.



A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N




ID
Band Level
Assigned Manager Level
ManLev02ID
ManLev03ID
ManLev04ID
ManLev05ID
ManLev06ID
ManLev07ID
ManLev08ID
ManLev09ID
ManLev10ID
ManLev11ID
Result


1111111
7bhn
8
2222222
3333333
4444444
5555555
6666666
7777777




6666666


6666666
5nv4
6
2222222
3333333
4444444
5555555






4444444



Assigned Manager Level is the column this employee corresponds to in the hierarchy. So if they are assigned manager level of 8 they will be under the column ManLev08ID. This employee will have a blank value in that spot for their own record but if they have a direct report they will show up on that direct report's hierarchy in the ManLEv08ID column.
So my logic was to grab the ID two levels above (we are looking for second-level managers) and then xlookup that ID using this same dataset to see if their band level is less than 6 which is the next criteria. If not I have to move on to the next. Here is an example of that scenario.



A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N




ID
Band Level
Assigned Manager Level
ManLev02ID
ManLev03ID
ManLev04ID
ManLev05ID
ManLev06ID
ManLev07ID
ManLev08ID
ManLev09ID
ManLev10ID
ManLev11ID
Result


1111111
7bhn
8
2222222
3333333
4444444
5555555
6666666
7777777




5555555


6666666
6vj4
6
2222222
3333333
4444444
5555555






4444444


5555555
5nv3
5
2222222
3333333
4444444







3333333



Here is my approach, not finished all the way because I don't think this would be the best approach. There has to be an easier way without having to write a long formula? Is there?
=IF(C2=11,IF(LEFT(XLOOKUP(K2,A:A,E:E),1)*1<6,K2,"Check Next Level"),
IF(C2=10,IF(LEFT(XLOOKUP(J2,A:A,E:E),1)*1<6,J2,"Check Next Level"),
IF(C2=9,IF(LEFT(XLOOKUP(I2,A:A,E:E),1)*1<6,I2,"Check Next Level"),
IF(C2=8,IF(LEFT(XLOOKUP(H2,A:A,E:E),1)*1<6,H2,"Check Next Level"),
IF(C2=7,IF(LEFT(XLOOKUP(G2,A:A,E:E),1)*1<6,G2,"Check Next Level"),
IF(C2=6,IF(LEFT(XLOOKUP(F2,A:A,E:E),1)*1<6,F2,"Check Next Level"),
IF(C2=5,IF(LEFT(XLOOKUP(E2,A:A,E:E),1)*1<6,E2,"Check Next Level"),
IF(C2=4,IF(LEFT(XLOOKUP(D2,A:A,E:E),1)*1<6,D2,"Check Next Level"),
IF(C2=3,"No Second-Level Leader",
IF(C2=2,"No Second-Level Leader","Not Found"))))))))))


Does your current formula yield correct result?

Which part is your expected outcome?

Expected outcome is the result column (Column N). The formula would work for the first table but not the second. It would work for any scenario where the two levels above the employees position is a manager at less than band 6. In the second table the manager is 3 levels above, but it could be 4 or 5 or 6, etc.

I don't understand why the lookup for manager's band level always returns the value from column E in your formula. Wouldn't it be the column that is headed 'Band Level', i.e. column B? Also it's not clear to me how the results for 6666666 and 5555555 get filled in without having 4444444 and 3333333 in the table to do the lookup.

The bit I'm really confused about is the second scenario. If you can't find a match for 6666666 with a band level less than 6, do you go on to the next one, 5555555? Then why isn't the result 5555555 or maybe 3333333?

Yes. You start two levels above the employees hierarchy position and then you keep going up if the ID does not correspond to the ID of someone who is a band 5 or lower number.

If I understand what you are trying to say, you want to get the id number of the second highest manager assigned to any given employee?  If so, just count the number of ids assigned to the given employee and return the second last one:
=INDEX(D3:M3,COUNT(D3:M3)-1)



The second criteria is that the ID has a band level number of 5 or lower. In the second scenario you see that is not the case so we have to try the next ID in the hierarchy to see if they are band 5 or lower.

@DanCue - I'm sorry, I honestly have no idea what you are trying to say.  So far as I can see, my formula is returning the same results you have shown in your examples.  Can you give me an example where my formula would not work correctly?

I’m an idiot. I’m sorry. I just corrected the second table. The result should be 5555555 for the first row. 6666666 is a band 6 therefore we need to go up to the next level that is band 5 or lower.

Try something like this:
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(D2:M2,FILTER(A$3:A$4,--LEFT(B$3:B$4)<C2-2))),D2:M2,"Not found",1,-1)

The idea is to try and match each of the managers for 1111111 in the table (filtered to include only managers more than two levels higher). Then search from the end of the row to find the manager with the highest numerical level which matches.


Couple of questions. Can I do A:A instead of A$3:A$4? Also, did you mean to put LEFT(B$3:B$4,1). I would also need to do B:B here.

Yes, no reason not to do A:A (or now even A.:.A) except if there's a possibility of an employee matching with themselves in which case you would have to exclude the current row. You can leave out the position parameter in left and it defaults to 1, and again B:B should work. However in practice A:A is very slow and you get an error even with A.:.A because it tries to convert the header to a number. You would have to catch the error with =XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(D2:M2,FILTER(A:A,IFERROR(--LEFT(B:B)<C2-2,0)))),D2:M2,"Not found",1,-1)

Probably =XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(D2:M2,FILTER(DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1),--LEFT(DROP(TOCOL(B:B,1),1))<C2-2,0))),D2:M2,"Not found",1,-1) is a better alternative

On your image above I see that your result (Col P) is not matching my desired result (Col N) for rows 3 and 4. Is it only bringing back a result if it is a band 5? It should bring back a result if it's <= 5.

I'm not understanding <C2-2. Is that making sure the result is at least 2 levels above or is it making sure it's at least band level of <= 5?

Making it more than 2 levels above, so in the original example if C2 was 8 that would be <6 or <=5. I wasn't sure that's what you meant but that's my reading of the question.

The other question, there's no data with a band level less than 4 or less than 3 respectively so it gives no match.

Man. I need some rest. I’ll test this out in a few. My apologies.

Looks like =XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(D2:M2,FILTER(A:A,IFERROR(--LEFT(B:B)<C2-2,0)))),D2:M2,"Not found",1,-1) seemed to work for the most part. I had to change <C2-2 to <6 because that made it look for a band level that was 2 lower. For band level we just wanted it to be less than 6. The hierarchy position is where the two positions matter. So I'm still trying to figure that one out. As it is with my modification if the first non-null value is less than a band 6 it would just bring that one back. I need it to disregard that first non-null value.
